# Arrange list of vectors

Tags: r, list, sorting

I have a list of vectors and an another vector. I would like the arrange the list of vectors according to values of the other vector

```
a <- c(1, 2)
b <- c(1, 4)
c <- c(1, 1)  
x <- list(a, b, c)  # list of vector
v <- c(3, 2, 5)     # other vector
```

Here I want arrange x according to v. So the desired output will be:

```
 2  b
 3  a
 5  c
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. `a`, `b`, `c` are variable *names* and `x` is a `list` of unnamed vectors. How do `"b"`, `"a"`, `"c"` show up in your expected output? What do you mean by *"arrange x according to v"*? DO you mean order numerically by values in `v`?

Answer (score 0):

First order list `x` based on order of vector `v` and then bind vector with take names of ordered list to form related column.

It will something like:

```
cbind(as.data.frame(v), col = names(x))[order(v),]
#  v col
#2 2   b
#1 3   a
#3 5   c
```

**Data:**

```
a <- c(1, 2)
b <- c(1, 4)
c <- c(1, 1)  
x <- list(a=a, b=b, c=c)  # list of vector
v <- c(3, 2, 5)     # other vector
```

Comment: It should be     2,3,5 . Not 3,2,5

Comment: @DipankarMondal Ahh. Understood. Probably you wanted to `sort` final output. Updated the answer. Have a look. Keep a note the creation of  `list x` has been changed slightly to define names.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `stack` and `arrange`

```
library(dplyr)
v %>%
   set_names(letters[1:3]) %>%
   stack %>%
   arrange(values)
#   values ind
#1      2   b
#2      3   a
#3      5   c
```